# Why I am getting a 415 response here?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, http-headers, fiddler, asp.net-core-webapi

I created the default Web API project using ASP.NET Core. That gave me following controller

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class ValuesController : Controller
    {
        // GET api/values
        [HttpGet]
        public IEnumerable<string> Get()
        {
            return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
        }

        // GET api/values/5
        [HttpGet("{id}")]
        public string Get(int id)
        {
            return "value";
        }

        // POST api/values
        [HttpPost]
        public void Post([FromBody]string value)
        {
        }

        // PUT api/values/5
        [HttpPut("{id}")]
        public void Put(int id, [FromBody]string value)
        {
        }

        // DELETE api/values/5
        [HttpDelete("{id}")]
        public void Delete(int id)
        {
        }
    }
```

I am using fiddler to test the api.

When I submit a GET request
http://localhost:21674/api/values
I get a JSON object with value1 and value2 values

When I try a post to same URL, I get an unsupported media type 415 response as shown below.
[Click here to see the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6r2yT.jpg)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It's `application/json`, not `application\json`

Comment: that doesn't seem to make any difference.

Comment: Out of curiosity does changing your request body to `{ value="test" }` work?

Comment: nops, still same 415 :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your request is forged wrong. There is no `application\json` mime-type.

The correct mime-type for JSON is `application/json` (notice the forward slash).

#### Update

Also you're not allowed to have quotes in it. The final header needs to be: `Content-Type: application/json`

Comment: See the update. You're not allow to have quotes in it

Answer (score 0):

Send { "value":"test"} json, not just "test".

Comment: Per Tseng suggestion, once i remove the double quote i was able to do it just with "test"